# Can't access MS Graph from Excel OData

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I was able to connect until recently from Excel OData to fetch users data using MS Graph API call

now it gives "Access to the resource is forbidden" error

Has something changed in settings somewhere?

Comment: What did you mean of  `From Excel OData to fetch users`? Did you want to fetch the users using MS Graph API? We will easily to understand your question if you provide some simple code.

Comment: kikang, read this - https://nilesh.live/2017/09/07/get-office-365-data-in-excel-using-ms-graph-api/. not working anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who comes here looking for an answer-
As per response from Microsoft Graph team, they have disabled OData feed for Graph API, due to security issues.
Hence fetching data using OData feed in MS Excel and Power BI will not work anymore.